# Open Button Cannot Work After Installing APK

Tags: android, installation

After installing an application, I press **Open** button, but the app does not open directly. Sometimes it opens, but sometimes it does not.

Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: might be throwing error, upload your code with errors ( if any ).

Comment: @Lucifer I cannot catch any errors. As soon as the app is installed, I press Open button it just goes to background.

Comment: that's why I am saying you to upload the code in the Question to help you better :)